# How to mask HTML-Unicode in Java

Tags: java, unicode, symbols, masking

How do I write a sign like ◄ and ► (funny... its not masked here by itself, here you go:) `&#9668;` and `&#9658;` in Java when I need this form `\u00df` (thats an "ß", fyi)... I tried just to put it in hex like `\u25BA` but that results in false symbols. What am I missing?

Please be so kind to post answer and method!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, the hex version works fine for me: `System.out.println("\u25C4 \u25BA");` (black arrows left/right) Could you provide further details on the problem?

Comment: You should clarify what is your need: in Java \u25BA and such should work. Where are you displaying it?

Comment: +1+1 Thanks! You guys are right, I wasn't thorough enough. Should've asked later. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Swing code works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String labelText = "\u25C4 \u25BA";
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText(labelText);
    panel.add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Are you doing something very different?

You can certainly mess it up by using fonts which do not support that character. So for example...

```
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.setText(labelText);

    // this font has the symbol
    field.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    panel.add(field);
    field = new JTextField();
    field.setText(labelText);

    // this font does not
    field.setFont(new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    panel.add(field);
    panel.add(field);
```

Comment: +1 Thanks!.. I'm being stupid! Its a font-thing, I guess. I tried it with _microsoft sans-serif_ in Java and thougt I crosschecked it with HTML... but I guess I effed up somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is in UTF-8:

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")
```

then you can leave the characters in the source. (Your IDE/editor has to be set to UTF-8 too.)

Comment: +1 Hello, thanks for the reply, but it doesn't apply to me. Its for a Swing-GUI and we mustn't use characters beside normal keyboard by convention, also I hear our buildserver (Bamboo) has got some trouble with it.

Comment: Joop is correct.  You need UTF-8 setup for the source file, compiler, and output.  Joop showed how to do this for webservers, but consoles are different.  Compiler can be done using the -encoding option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the encoding-option... but as I said its neither web nor console... its GUI.